# Is $\mathbb{R}^\omega$ a completely normal space, in the box topology?

Tags: general-topology

Basically, what the title says. Is $\mathbb{R}^\omega$ a [completely normal space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completely_normal_space) in the [box topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box_topology) ?
($\mathbb{R}^\omega$ is the space of sequences to $\mathbb{R}$)
Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

Quoting Munkres from his book  *Topology*  (this remark is made in the 5th exercise of section 32):

> It is not known whether $\mathbb{R}^{\omega}$ is normal in the box topology. Mary-Ellen Rudin has shown that the answer is affirmative if one assumes the continuum hypothesis [RM]. In fact, she shows it satisfies a stronger condition called *paracompactness*. 
>   [RM] M. E. Rudin. The box product of countably many compact metric spaces.  *General Topology and Its Applications* , 2:293-298, 1972.

Of course this doesn't rule out the possibility that it is not completely normal.

Comment: I showed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3040317/4280) the answer is no.